Proverbs 20:27 The spirit of man is the candle of the LORD

Pro 20:27 The spirit of man is the candle of the LORD

Any commentary to understand this verse?

The verse is best understood if it is quoted in full. Here are three representative translations.

A lamp from the Lord is human life-breath;
it searches through the inmost being. NABRE

The spirit of man is the candle of the Lord, searching all the inward parts of his being. KJ21

The human spirit is the lamp of the Lord that sheds light on one’s inmost being. NIV


The meaning is fairly clear if one considers the function of the candle or lamp. It is to illuminate one's inner being. In other words, by providing us with the spirit (niš·maṯ - נִשְׁמַ֣ת) God has gifted us with the means to understand ourselves deeply, perhaps completely. The term used for "spirit" is also used in Gen. 2 when God breathes the "breath of life" into Adam. This idea is echoed in
Job 32:8:

But there is a spirit in human beings, the breath of the Almighty,
that gives them understanding.


Proverb 20:27

The human spirit (Strong's 5397) is the lamp of the Lord
that sheds light on one’s inmost being. (NIV)


The spirit  of man is the candle of the Lord, searching all the inward parts of the belly. (KJV)

Genesis 2:7

Then the Lord God formed a man from the dust of the ground and breathed (Strong's 5397) into his nostrils the breath of life, and the man became a living being.

Recognizing the Lord's omniscience is crucial. As stated in Hebrews 4:13, "Nothing in all creation is hidden from God’s sight. Everything is uncovered and laid bare before the eyes of him to whom we must give account."
Proverb 20:27 explains that the spirit given to us by the Lord acts as a lamp, illuminating the innermost parts of our being, and exposing all hidden aspects to His sight.
The Old Testament consistently acknowledges the Lord's all-knowing nature, especially in verses like Jeremiah 17:10 and Psalm 139:1-4, underscoring His ability to judge humanity with divine insight.
Jeremiah 17:10 (NIV)

“I the Lord search the heart
and examine the mind,
to reward each person according to their conduct,
according to what their deeds deserve.”

Psalm 139:1-4 (NIV)

1 You have searched me, Lord,
and you know me.
2 You know when I sit and when I rise;
you perceive my thoughts from afar.
3 You discern my going out and my lying down;
you are familiar with all my ways.
4 Before a word is on my tongue
you, Lord, know it

